# Matlab - Create RBF Network without using Neural Network Toolbox

Tags: matlab, neural-network, gaussian

In the lectures we only mention how to train the RBF network with Gausian function and how to use the "newrb" tool box in Matlab.  But in the assignemnet I need to create my own RBF network which using the NN toolbox is forbidden.  Basically I not even know how to start it and our professor not willing to provide any information.

With some tips I have write my own program but the performance is very bad, I am wonder if any one can give me some helpful tutorial or guides that how to create the RBF network with Gaussian function without using NN toolbox.

I have used k-means to obtain the centers and gaussian function to caculuate the weights, the main probrlem is that I have no idea how to design the method that transform the Input matrix to the RBF matrix. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly homework, and it's not clear what your question is.  But I think you are wondering how to create the Gram matrix.  If so, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

You should have the math for how to do each step in your textbook and/or notes.